# structure padding information

Tags: c, struct, padding, unions, bit-fields

```
struct abc
{
  char arr[7];
  char arr1[2];
  int i:24;
};
```

In the above structure using sizeof operator I got its size 12 byte. But according to my calculation (may be wrong) it should be 16 byte. Why it is giving 12 bytes?

Another question:

According to C99 section 6.7.2.1 paragraph 14

> Each non-bit-filed member of a structure or union object is aligned in
>   an implementation defined manner appropriate to its type.

For a particular implementation, where will I get the documentation that describes how a specific compiler(e.g gcc) introduces padding in a structure? Is there any general rule for all compilers for a specific architecture?

Comment: **Implementation defined** means that each implementation is free to do it in the way(*there is no common rule*) they want to but they do need to document the behavior. So this documentation needs to be provided by the respective compiler & you should be able to find it if you do some searching.

Comment: Why would it be 16? `char` arrays do not need alignment, and `i` is a three-byte bit field, so it's 7+2+3=12.

Comment: Typically the implementations follow the platform ABI. Any compiler that goes against the platform condemns itself to a solitary existence with no interop.

Comment: @EF `arr` is seven bytes, `arr1` is two bytes, `i` is three bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Structure layout is implementation defined. And it turns out that the default layout used by GCC differs from the layout used by MSVC, for example. I'm guessing that you are used to the way MSVC lays out structs that contain bitfields.

There is, of course, a GCC attribute, `ms_struct`, to allow you to change behaviour. This is described in more detail in the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#i386-Variable-Attributes).

So, this struct has size 16:

```
struct abc
{
  char arr[7];
  char arr1[2];
  int i:24;
} __attribute__((ms_struct));
```

If you use the `gcc_struct` option, the default, then the size is 12.

> For a particular implementation, where will I get the documentation that describes how a specific compiler(e.g GCC) introduces padding in a structure?

You need to consult the documentation of each compiler. In the case of GCC, the [documentation says](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit_002dfields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit_002dfields-implementation):

> **4.9 Structures, unions, enumerations, and bit-fields**
>
> - A member of a union object is accessed using a member of a different type (C90 6.3.2.3).
>   The relevant bytes of the
>     representation of the object are treated as an object of the type used
>     for the access. See Type-punning. This may be a trap representation.
> - Whether a “plain” int bit-field is treated as a signed int bit-field or as an unsigned int bit-field (C90 6.5.2, C90 6.5.2.1, C99
>     6.7.2, C99 6.7.2.1).
>   By default it is treated as signed int but this may be changed by the -funsigned-bitfields option.
> - Allowable bit-field types other than _Bool, signed int, and unsigned int (C99 6.7.2.1).
>   No other types are permitted in
>     strictly conforming mode.
> - Whether a bit-field can straddle a storage-unit boundary (C90 6.5.2.1, C99 6.7.2.1).
>   Determined by ABI.
> - The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (C90 6.5.2.1, C99 6.7.2.1).
>   Determined by ABI.
> - The alignment of non-bit-field members of structures (C90 6.5.2.1, C99 6.7.2.1).
>   Determined by ABI.
> - The integer type compatible with each enumerated type (C90 6.5.2.2, C99 6.7.2.2).
>   Normally, the type is unsigned int if there are
>     no negative values in the enumeration, otherwise int. If -fshort-enums
>     is specified, then if there are negative values it is the first of
>     signed char, short and int that can represent all the values,
>     otherwise it is the first of unsigned char, unsigned short and
>     unsigned int that can represent all the values.
>   On some
>     targets, -fshort-enums is the default; this is determined by the ABI.

So, by and large, you need to work out what the ABI for your platform is. That's really the sane thing for any compiler to do. If it doesn't layout structs according to the ABI, then it makes interop exceedingly tricky.

What's a bit odd is that GCC's view as to what the ABI is on Windows differs from the MSVC implementation. I've got no insight as to why that is so.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

```
struct abc
{
  char arr[7];  // occupies 7 bytes
  char arr1[2]; // occupies 2 bytes
  int i:24;     // occupies 3 bytes
};
```

Now, in the 3rd declaration (of `i`), only 3 bytes are needed. You already have this as follows:

```
0 1 2 3 // All 4 bytes used for `char arr[7]`
0 1 2 3 // 3 more used for `char arr[7]`, 1 used for `char arr1[2]`
0 1 2 3 // 1 used for `char arr1[2]`, and the remaining 3 bytes will be used for `int i:24`
```

But if you use `int i` (no bitfield), it will consume 16 bytes, because

```
0 1 2 3 // All 4 bytes used for `char arr[7]`
0 1 2 3 // 3 more used for `char arr[7]`, 1 used for `char arr1[2]`
0 1 2 3 // 1 used for `char arr1[2]`, there are still 3 bytes but we need 4 bytes for an `int`
0 1 2 3 // So the compiler will allocate a new 4 byte chunk for `int i`
```

I think it's pretty clear now.

Comment: Different compilers have 3 bytes padding after arr1, and 1 byte padding after i. So, the question is why that should be so? I think it's pretty obvious how that struct is laid out if its size is 12. I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Its depend on compiler that how it manages its memory. In GCC the same structure(mentioned by you) will sized as 12 bytes, at the same time in Visual C compiler will size it as 16 bytes. Because it depends how the compiler follows the standard & implements it.

Comment: Well quite. That's the crux of the question. I am quite sure that @fuzzy can see how the 12 byte layout would be arranged.